# How to get Complete list of available Datasets in a Project (VS)

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, datatable, dataset

I want to get a list of all available datasets (that I'd creat in my Asp.net project)

After that I want to select a Dataet from the list and get The list of Available DataTable included in that Dataset.

Finally I should b able to check all Data Tables Fields

How To Do This ?

---

Note that I know VS already has a dataset Panel but thats too heavy and I want to create my own panel. so please do not recommand to use this one.

Comment: Do you want to create a plug-in for VS or do you want this runtime?

Comment: @Henk - You guess right. I want to create a plug-in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Load the executing assembly using reflection and see getPropertyInfo function, it will help you a lot. [This post](https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://articles.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/5100-10878_11-6099345.html) from tech-republic may help you